# Choose Game Center section destination

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, game-center

I'm using this function to open Game Center. It opens Achievements by default an I then have to click the next section to see the leaderboard. Is it possible to open the leaderboard directly?

```
func showLeaderBoard() {

    let ViewController = self.view.window?.rootViewController
    let gcvc = GKGameCenterViewController()

    gcvc.gameCenterDelegate = self

    ViewController?.present(gcvc, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

On the picture below you can see that it by default opens Achievements. I'm looking for a way for it to open directly in Leaderboards.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should assign [viewState](https://developer.apple.com/reference/gamekit/gkgamecenterviewcontrollerstate) property of [GKGameCenterViewController](https://developer.apple.com/reference/gamekit/gkgamecenterviewcontroller). Try this

```
func showLeaderBoard() {

    let ViewController = self.view.window?.rootViewController
    let gcvc = GKGameCenterViewController()
    gcvc.gameCenterDelegate = self
    gcvc.viewState = GKGameCenterViewControllerState.Leaderboards

    ViewController?.present(gcvc, animated: true, completion: nil)
 }
```

Comment: Works perfectly. Exactly what I was looking for!